# How to know the size of a scaled HTML 5 canvas context?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm writing an image to a canvas and then scaling the context and re-writing it to the same canvas. I can't figure out how to get the exact size of the scaled area once it's written back to the canvas. I need the size in pixels so I can calculate the translate offset to keep it centered on the canvas no matter the scale.

The canvas/context looks like this.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

And I'm applying the scale like this (to scale it up by .1).

```
scale = scale * '1.1';
img_w = img.width * scale;
img_y = img.height * scale;
ctx.scale('1.1', '1.1');
```

Then, I'm using

```
ctx.drawImage(img, (canvas.width - img_w) / 2, (canvas.height - img_h) / 2);
```

to redraw the image and this is where it fails since I don't have the exact width of the scaled area.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/robertsdavidb/bGyFT/13/

The scaling works fine, but how do I keep it in the center after scaling?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bGyFT/16/ – you have to apply the scaling to the canvas width and height in your calculation.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. Here's the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/robertsdavidb/bGyFT/36/